# FreeIPA remove read and search permission

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I want to disable the read and search permission that is granted to all user accounts by default. I don't want users to be able to display other users informations.

is this possible? and is there other operations that might be effected if I do so?

Comment: I found what I was looking for here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906586/aci-tips-in-opends-i-want-to-restrict-attribute-read-access-to-bound-dn-only